# Joomla 3 and gantry 4 compatibility

Tags: php, frameworks, joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0

What is the compatible Gantry version for the Joomla 3.o Latest version. i have tried with gantry 4.0.5 and 4.0.3 bundle , both gives me errors.

> Call to undefined method JAdministrator::get() in D:\wamp\www\Joomla_3.0.0-Stable-Full_Package\tmp\install_506876ffb73aa\install.script.php on line 293

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gantry 4 isn't yet fully compatible with Joomla 3.0 as the stable release only came out a few days ago. For a little more information about is, please read this:

http://www.rockettheme.com/forum/index.php?f=15&t=175669&p=864744&rb_v=viewtopic#p864744

**Update:** Gantry 4 is now Joomla 3.x compatible